# Python scikit - Image detect and remove lines from a noise image

Tags: python, scikit-image, image-preprocessing

I want to remove lines from a noise image like:

[IMAGE_NOISED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vv1EJ.png)

I used morphological operations such erosion, dilation, and filters like thresholding, denoise tv, to remove most part of noise, but I have these lines on this image and want to remove then, I already tried hough lines, let us discuss about techniques, function or algorithms to extract lines from image?

And are there any technique based on machine learning to pre - process images?

I tested most of the algorithms present in this link:
[Scikit Image - Examples](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/)

And I did not get good results :( .

Comment: I find it difficult to see the noise in your example. I just see red, yellow and black lines on white background. Could you maybe specify where the noise in the image is?

Comment: @Trilarion i atualized the image ^^

Comment: Maybe a fourier transform can help you, try transforming the image to see if the lines show up as a specific pattern, then you can treat the transformed image and transform it back

Comment: How many times you eroded/dilated your image? Sometimes I apply these operators more than once and the amount of doesn't necessarily needs to be equal, as well as the order you do them is arbitrary.